# Segmentation Fault when accessing (non-pointer) member variable in Qt class instance

Tags: c++, qt

I am having some issues with a segmentation fault being caused by access
to a member variable in a Qt application.  My experience of segmentation
faults have shown them generally to be a result of accessing a memory 
location that is out of bounds.  However, I'm struggling to figure out 
why this would be the case in my code.

The class in question is a subclass of QFrame and contains a number of 
member variables, including one originally called `m_Zoom` of type 
`unsigned int`.  When the frame is created, a number of functions are called 
that cause the zoom level to be set and then the window is drawn.  This 
all works fine.  There are then a number of ways that the zoom level can 
be changed: opening a new file or pressing either + or -.  These read 
the existing zoom level and then decide whether to change it.  Simply 
reading the existing zoom level causes a segmentation fault.

Note that this variable is not a pointer or in an array or anything 
unusual.  The definition was along the lines of:

```
class MyClass : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void SetZoomLevel(unsigned int zoom);
    void ZoomIn();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    // A number of private functions for performing calculations

    // Some variables including:
    double m_OriginShift;
    unsigned int m_Zoom;
    // Some more variables
};
```

The function `paintEvent` and all the `mouse*` event functions access 
`m_Zoom` and these work fine (the mouse is used to move the view 
around).  The constructor calls `SetZoomLevel` (which is basically 
`m_Zoom = zoom`).  Again, this works with no problems.  `ZoomIn` starts 
with:

```
void MyClass::ZoomIn()
{
    qDebug() << "Zoom In";
    unsigned int existingZoom = m_Zoom; // [1]
    qDebug() << "Existing zoom is " << existingZoom;

    ...
```

The segmentation fault happens in this function, before the second 
`qDebug` reports anything.

I've tried stepping through the application in cygwin's gdb and I get to 
the line marked `[1]` and type `stepi` and get an immediate segfault.

Having moved the variable around (in case something else was overwriting 
it's location), changed to using a pointer with `malloc`d memory, moved 
it into a separate structure, moved it into a separate class (both with a member instance and with a member pointer with a `new` line in the constructor) and 
probably a few other random and unsuccessful acts of desperation, I've 
completely run out of ideas.

Please can anyone suggest any good ways that I could go about debugging 
this issue?

I'm using Qt 4.6.3 on Windows XP compiling with GNU Make 3.81 and g++ 
version 4.4.0 (from the mingw that came with the Qt installer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While this is a wild guess, there's a possibility that you're calling that method on a null object.

Note that:

```
unsigned int existingZoom = m_Zoom;
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned int existingZoom = this->m_Zoom;
```

If you called this method from a null pointer:

```
someUninitializedPtr->ZoomIn();
```

then this is probably the result you'd get - a segmentation fault upon first try of dereferencing `this` pointer, having the value of `null`.

Comment: Bingo!  I was being completely dense and trying to fix it in the wrong place.  It turns out that I had an old `MyClass *m_scene` in the main window definition that had been deprecated by the promotion mechanism in the `.ui` file.  However, when I was calling `ZoomIn()`, I was calling `m_scene->ZoomIn()` instead of `ui.scene->ZoomIn()`.  I was being thrown by the fact that the debug still worked.  Thanks for the help.